# Converting Back to Human-Friendly Timer Format in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have a timer running in one of my react-native components. It is working as expected with the following code:

```
const visitItemCounter = (value) => {
  const [duration, setCounter] = useState(moment.duration(value).asMilliseconds());
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('duration: ', duration);
      setCounter(duration => duration + 1000);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []); 

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.texts.mediumText}>{ duration }</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

By the way, in the console I see the following, the value in milliseconds:

```
duration:  65849000
```

So that value increases by 1000 every second, as expected and desired.

All I want to do now is use `moment.js` to convert the display from milliseconds into typical, human-friendly format.

Now, in the final display, I want to convert back to human-friendly format. To do that I do the following. I just change one line from this:

```
setCounter(duration => duration + 1000);
```

to this:

```
  setCounter(duration => moment.utc(duration + 1000).format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

So the entire block now looks like this:

```
const visitItemCounter = (value) => {
  console.log('counter running with duration: ', value);
  // let duration = moment.utc(props.item.duration).format('HH:mm:ss');
  const [duration, setCounter] = useState(moment.duration(value).asMilliseconds());
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('duration 42: ', duration);
      setCounter(duration => moment.utc(duration + 1000).format('HH:mm:ss'));
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []); // Pass in empty array to run effect only once!

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.texts.mediumText}>{ duration }</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I would think this would work, but while I am get the initial value printing to the screen correctly, when it goes to increment to the next value, this prints instead: `invalid date`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set the duration itself to the formatted output (because then when you do `moment.utc(duration + 1000).format('HH:mm:ss')`, it will be trying to do `moment.utc("12:34:12" + 1000)` which gives you an invalid date.

Instead, simply format the string when you output it:

```
 console.log('duration 42: ', moment.utc(duration).format('HH:mm:ss'));
 <Text style={styles.texts.mediumText}>{ moment.utc(duration).format('HH:mm:ss') }</Text>
```

Comment: That gives me a different error: `duration.format is not a function`?

Comment: sorry, should have been `moment.utc(duration).format`